Editing formatting for notices in DITA OT pdf plugin
I am new to DITA OT and trying to develop a custom pdf plugin. I have topics attached to a ditamap as topicrefs that have their otherprops='legal' and I am trying to get the pdf to print them before the TOC and on a different style master page. I assume that this is what the "notices" topic type exists for but please someone correct me if I'm wrong!
I have tried editing the determineTopicType template in commons.xsl to include an or statement that captures topicrefs on the map that have otherprops='legal' and then editing the processTopicNotices template to use new attribute sets which I then defined in commons-attr.xsl and topic-attr.xsl which has no visible effect.
I also tried to create a new master page and page-sequence and then apply those during topic processing but it seemed like topic notices was created to handle exactly this case so I gave up thinking I was trying to reinvent the wheel. Now I'm trying to use the notices feature to get it to print these topicrefs on notices pages and page-sequence.  Below is the updated or statement added to the determineTopicType template and the processTopicNotices template.
        <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/notices ') or @otherprops='legal']" mode="determineTopicType">
        <xsl:text>topicNotices</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="processTopicNotices">
        <xsl:variable name="atts" as="element()">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="key('map-id', ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')][1]/@id)/ancestor::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/backmatter ')]">
                    <dummy xsl:use-attribute-sets="page-sequence.backmatter.notice"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <dummy xsl:use-attribute-sets="page-sequence.notice"/> 
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="body-sequence">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$atts/@*"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="startPageNumbering"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertPrefaceStaticContents"/>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="notices">
                    <!-- TODO: Replace with mode="commonattributes" -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
                    <xsl:if test="empty(ancestor::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')])">
                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="current-topic-number">
                          <xsl:variable name="topicref" 
                            select="key('map-id', ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')][1]/@id)[1]"
                            as="element()?"
                          />
                          <xsl:for-each select="$topicref">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="topicTitleNumber"/>
                          </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:marker>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="insertTopicHeaderMarker"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="customTopicMarker"/>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' topic/prolog ')]"/>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="insertChapterFirstpageStaticContent">
                        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'notices'"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>

                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="topic.title.notices">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="customTopicAnchor"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="pullPrologIndexTerms"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' ditaot-d/ditaval-startprop ')]"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')]">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="getTitle"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:block>

                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="$noticesLayout='BASIC'">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="* except(*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ') or contains(@class,' ditaot-d/ditaval-startprop ') or
                              contains(@class, ' topic/prolog ') or contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')])"/>
                          <!--xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="buildRelationships"/-->
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="createMiniToc"/>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="pullPrologIndexTerms.end-range"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
   </xsl:template>


To be honest, I don't understand what you try to achieve and I've the feeling you have not yet figured out the correct approach. Could you please share your entire plugin and give some more detailed explanations? Maybe it would be a better idea to open a discussion on https://github.com/orgs/dita-ot/discussions/

@StefanJung Thanks for the recommendation, I'll try the dita-ot discussions on github as well.  What I'm trying to accomplish:  I have a ditamap that will be published as a pdf book. There is a topic attached to the map that has an attribute "otherprops" in the topicref that is set to "legal" and is all the legal notices for the book. I want that topic to appear between the frontmatter and the ToC and to be on a page that has a different background than other topics. I can't post all my code because it contains proprietary information for my job.
